# Communications link failure - Connect to MySQL with PhpStorm

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, phpstorm, ovh

I'm trying to connect my MySQL database (that I got from [OVH](https://www.ovh.com/)) with PhpStorm, but I continuously got the same error:

```
Connection to <NAME> failed.
[08S01] Communications link failure.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I have searched a lot, but I still can't understand where this error comes from, or what to do to connect to my database. Is it even possible?

I've been stuck with that the whole day, so I will be glad for any information you can give me...

*Edit*: I know I didn't give you a lot of details, because I really don't know what could be useful. But I will gladly edit my post with more information.

Comment: Are you connecting to a machine name or IP address?

Comment: I think it's a machine name, since the host is in that form: dbname.mysql.db. Not sure what this really means though, I could be wrong.

Comment: can you show a code snippet of what you have?

Comment: That's the thing: I'm not using any code since I'm setting this connexion directly in PhpStorm, so I can't know where the error comes from exactly... :/

Comment: So .. that's some sort of online hosting. Am I correct? If yes -- this means that you most likely would not be able to connect from PhpStorm directly (usually DB servers do not allow connections from internet) .. unless you will do it via SSH tunnel (which PhpStorm supports). Check your OVH support section or something for instructions. If I'm wrong in my assumption -- provide some more details...

Comment: No I think you're probably right, that should be the explanation. Sad thing is: my OVH plan doesn't allow me to use SSH. I think I will have to duplicate my database on localhost in order to test some functionalities...

Comment: do you know how to do it?

Comment: Not really, I'm a complete begginer with PhpStorm. But maybe I should make some research or ask another question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting OVH support, it seems that @LazyOne was correct: I simply cannot connect to the database using my local computer. The connection is only possible from PhpMyAdmin. Hence the error I got.

This closed this question I believe, since the only possibility for me is to subscribe to another Database Plan (to get a database accessible from outside the datacenter).